# extract word from string that have combination of letter and number in java?

Tags: java, regex

this is my first question and sorry for my bad English

I want to extract only word from String that have combination of letter and number and store it in array

I try this code, but I don't get what I want

```
String temp = "74 4F 4C 4F 49 65  brown fox jump over the fence";
String [] word = temp.split("\\W");
```

this is the result that I want (only word and no empty array)

```
brown
fox
jump
over
the
fence
```

Please help, Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
String temp = "74 4F 4C 4F 49 65  brown fox jump over the fence";
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?:^|\\s+)([a-z]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(temp);
while (m.find())
    arr.add(m.group(1));

// convert to String[]
String[] word = arr.toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println( Arrays.toString(word) );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[brown, fox, jump, over, the, fence]
```

Comment: This will also give `F C F` =(

Comment: I try your code but the first index of array is empty, and letter from 4F 4C 4F is in the array too. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The regex is easily fixed by 
    String [] word = temp.split("\w[^A-Za-z]+\w");

(assuming Java supports the \w word boundary indicator).

Comment: @AriefTaufikurrahman: Let me correct, sorry I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @CompuChip : how to make java support that \w ??

Comment: wow...but, how to store it to array automatically like split ??

Comment: @anubhava: How to store it to "conventional" array ( String [] arr) ??

Answer (score 3):

Based on @anubhava's answer, you could do something like

```
String temp = "74 4F 4C 4F 49 65  brown fox jump over the fence";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Za-z]+\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);

while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println("Matched " + matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for:

[android](/questions/tagged/android) [java](/questions/tagged/java)

---

There are already some answers here but this is the one I'd preferred to do that. Try this code:

```java
List<String> wordsOnlyList = new ArrayList<>(); // This list contains all the words without numbers or special chars
String sentence = "I bought a A7A for $36,000"; // This is a sample sentence to test the result
String[] words = sentence.split(" "); // split into each word

for(String word : words){
   if (!(Pattern.compile("[^a-z ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(word).find())) { //checking if it has only alphabets
      // it has only alphabets
      wordsOnlyList.add(word); // add the word to the list
   }
}

System.out.println(wordsOnlyList.toString()); // display in console
```

Result:

```
[I, bought, a, for]
```

You can also test the code from [here](https://onecompiler.com/java/3y22z6he2).